# Why does T-CNN output have a channel of 64?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, detection

[image]

"Network architecture of T-CNN. We refer kernel with shape d×h×w where d is the kernel depth, h and w are height and width. Output matrix with shape C×D×H×W where C is number of channels, D is the number of frames, H and W are the height and width of frame. toi-pool2 only exists in TPN."

The table above is taken from a paper published about T-CNN (REF: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10664.pdf)

The paper is about activity detection from videos using a 3D convolutional model.

Given the kernel, I assume here for the small d, it corresponds to the frame. We're working on video clips with 300 height x 400 width and 8 frames. I assume it is RGB and has 3 channels.

I do not understand how the output dimension is obtained, can someone please help explain how the channel (C) is 64?

How does the kernel take into account RGB when convoluting?